# Growl works easy way but not hard way, blockUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, blockui

when I use this it works perfectly,

```
$.growlUI('Growl Notification', 'Have a nice day!');
```

but when I replace it with this, (it doesn't work)

```
 $.blockUI({
     message: $('div.growlUI'),
     fadeIn: 700,
     fadeOut: 700,
     timeout: 2000,
     showOverlay: false,
     centerY: false,
     css: {
         width: '350px',
         top: '10px',
         left: '',
         right: '10px',
         border: 'none',
         padding: '5px',
         backgroundColor: '#000',
             '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
             '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
         opacity: .6,
         color: '#fff'
     }
 });
```

reason I am trying hard way is because I want to change color of growl, can I add css to `$.growlUI('` anyway ?

also if i can add `fadeIn: 700,` to  uigrowl

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

Comment: No enough information. Create jsfiddle so we could check what is wrong.

Comment: @IgorS. what else information you need ? and JSfiddle doesn't support blockUI, you might need to do some reading, before putting a useless comment, thanks

Comment: If it's work on website you probable missing something. jsfiddle is polite reminder, check your code before posting useless questions.

Comment: Please explain how your code is different from working example on website?

Comment: What's the content of $('div.growlUI') ?

Comment: or maybe... have you created a div with the growlUI class and put your markup inside?

Comment: @DocKuro I even exchanged "div.growlUI" to "mymessage" but still no luck, I am just following the website to be honest

Comment: @user13814 if you ever used jquery you should know that $() should contain a css selector, so in your webpage you have to create a div with the growlUI class (if you want to follow the example) and put inside it the markup for your message, like <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works fine, I'm pretty sure you just forgot to add the content of the $('div.growlUI') selector.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xcT4L/

I just added

```
<div class="growlUI" style="display: none">
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

in the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old question, but you can also simply override `$.blockUI.defaults.growlCSS` to supply your own styles.

If you want to `$.blockUI` properties like `fadeIn`, you can change the `$.growlUI` definition in **jquery.blockUI.js** to pass in an `opts` object, then you can set any properties you want there.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/hM3KX/2/